# JavaScript Flipbook - Div content not selectable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a Flipbook based on this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0kD6ff2J3BQ

It uses papers, each paper has two sides (front and back). Basically when the next button is pressed it increases the Z-Index value by one and adds the 'flipped' class to the div (turning the page).
Each paper has a p+number id, e.g. p1, p2, p3, etc.

This is the function for the next button:

```
const elementsWithNumberedIds = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('[id]')
 ).filter(el => /^p\d+$/.test(el.id));
const totalPapers = elementsWithNumberedIds.length;

const papers = {};
for (let i = 1; i <= totalPapers; i++) {  
    papers[`paper${i}`] = document.querySelector(`#p${i}`);
}

let currentLocation = 1;
let numOfPapers = totalPapers;
let maxLocation = numOfPapers + 1;

function goNextPage() {
    console.log("Current Location value Next prior click: ", currentLocation);

    if (currentLocation < maxLocation) {
        openBook();
        const currentPage = papers[`paper${currentLocation}`];
        if (currentPage) {
            currentPage.classList.add("flipped");
            currentPage.style.zIndex = currentLocation;
            console.log("Current Page: ", currentPage);
            if (currentLocation === maxLocation - 1) {
                closeBook(false);
            }
            currentLocation++;
        } else {
            throw new Error("Unknown state");
        }
    }
    console.log("Current Location value Next after click: ", currentLocation);
}
```

And this is a sample of the HTML, each paper has the same structure (front and back):

```
    <!-- Paper 6 -->
    <div id="p6" class="paper">
        <div class="front">
            <div id="f6" class="front-content">
                <div style="width: 80%;">
                    <p>My Text for page 11 Here!</p>
                    <footer>Page 11</footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div id="b6" class="back-content">
                <div style="width: 80%">
                    <p>My Text for page 12 Here!</p>
                    <footer>Page 12</footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

(it's all wrapped by a div (no CSS on it)).

Issue is, when I get to page 11 on the front-end, text is not selectable. Which is an issue when trying to add links.

This is the CSS:

```
.front,
.back {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    border-radius: 15px;

}

.front {
    z-index: 1;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-left: 3px solid rgb(39, 37, 48);
}

.back {
    z-index: 0;
}

.front-content,
.back-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.back-content {
    transform: rotateY(180deg)
}

.flipped .front,
.flipped .back {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

So far, it has happened with the 'front' elements exclusively.
Anybody has any suggestion?